# Can't open any question

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oops! Something Bad Happened!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85824/oops-something-bad-happened)

Every time I try to open a question i get this error:

```
Oops! Something Bad Happened!
```

What's going on?

Comment: The dupe target doesn't seem to exist, unless this is intended as some kind of irony :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Site is currently down it seems. Other stackexchange sites seem to be functional and that this is just isolated to StackOverflow.